# Is org-capture broken?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, emacs26

I use emacs-26.1 org-version 9.1.14.

My templates (list) is showing up but when I choose a template I get:

org-capture: Capture abort: (void-function org-eldoc-load)

I can't find org-eldoc.el in my org installation.

Comment: I put the org-eldoc.el from https://github.com/thisirs/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/ in load-path, and now it works. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It used to work and now stopped working without any changes in your config? I don't think that org-eldoc is required for capturing directly.

Comment: Maybe `org-eldoc.el`'s autoload cookie, `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-eldoc-load)`, is somehow executed. Because it seems in your Emacs, loading org will require org-eldoc. It should not be very hard to find out what's going on.